# ethernet connection via ros

Tags: ros, ethernet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys,

i am trying to connect my laptop via LAN to my robot. So my question is, are there already ethernet interfaces for ros? With which a NODE can access on the Ethernet port? For example I can ping my robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195514/ethernet-connection-via-ros/) by [Hankmasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/20541/hankmasta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At first would I suggest you to synchonize your robot installing chrony

```
$sudo apt-get install chrony
```

then, if you have the later versions of Ubuntu you have access to Zeroconf which simplyfies a lot the whole story.
With hostname you can find the name of your machine, for istance:

```
$ hostname
my_computer

$ hostname
my_robot
```

Now I suggest you the following trick: just add .local at the end of your hostname, then you can do all operations you want to:

```
$ping my_robot.local
```

and f course:

```
$ping my_robot.local
```

after that set the ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_HOSTNAME in yur robt and desktop as in the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup).
Hope it helps

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0